# (Complex number modulo Complex Number) $\mathbb{C} /n \mathbb{C}$

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, topological-groups

i know there is a post about $\mathbb{C} / \mathbb{Z}$, but what elements does $\mathbb{C} /n \mathbb{C}$ contain?

Answer (score 1):

Every complex number $z$ is a multiply of every other complex number $w$ over $\mathbb C$. $z = z/w * w$.

So your quotient is a special case with $w = n$. Thus, the quotient is actually the trivial group $\{e\}$.

Comment: oh, thank you, i´m a bit disappointed that it is that trivial tho :(
but does that mean that $\mathbb{Z} /n \mathbb{Z}$ with the * and + of complex numbers is a group too ?
(for n= prime ofc)

Comment: $\mathbb Z/ n \mathbb Z$ as a ring is still a ring. It is in fact a field when $n$ is prime.

Comment: but im talking about $\mathbb{Z} /n \mathbb{Z}$ with
 +:= (a+b) + (c+d) = (a+c) , (b+d) 
and 
x := (a+b)(c+d) = (ac-bd) + (ad+bc)

Comment: On $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$, I'm not even sure what's going in those operations. It looks like you're just ignoring some of the summands in addition, which would mean this thing isn't commutative, and possibly not associative either...